# Wait com AlertDialog()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

boas!
Meu problema é com o `AlertDialog` assíncrono do `Xamarin.Android`. Eu tenho uma classe com um método que monto um alerta com alguns campos... Com os dados desses campos, eu monto um objeto para fazer meu `CRUD`. 
O problema está na hora de chamar o `AlertDialog`, quando chamo, ele é montado e logo instancia meu objeto com os valores vazios do `AlertDialog`, pois é assíncrono.

```
llCompraAtiva.Click += delegate
{
    this.RunOnUiThread(() => dadosCompra = Util.modalPagamento(this));
    string teste = dadosCompra.NumCartao;
};
```

Pensei em montar algo com `Thread`, mas não me saí bem...

Resumindo: Preciso digitar os dados nos inputs, depois instanciar o objeto com os valores desses inputs.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? 
Tks

Comment: Qual o retorno de: Util.modalPagamento(this) ? É um Task<DadosCompra> ?

Comment: Esquece, confundi com Xamarin.Forms =D

Comment: Hahaha, sem problemas, me ajudou alot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é recomendado bloquear a Thread principal para esperar pelo Dialog, portanto, você precisa fornecer o handler para o proprio Dialog para ele tratar, assim quando o usuário confirmar a ação no Dialog, este, vai acionar o handler para preencher o objeto.

Escrevi um exemplo, mas não tive tempo de testar, acho que vai te dar uma ideia

```
using (var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
{
    var title = "Edite seus detalhes: ";
    builder.SetTitle(title);
    builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", OkAction);                
    var customDialog = builder.Create();
    customDialog.Show();
}
```

E o handler do botão:

```
private void OkAction(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
{
    var botao = sender as Button; 
    if (botao != null)
    {
        var resultado = BuscaResultado();
        _dadosCompra.NumeroCartao = resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consegui aqui, me ajudou bastante! Obrigado @FBatista